# Inflating ListView with another ListView dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, google-maps-android-api-2, layout-inflater

I've got an empty ListView which has to contain another n different ListViews, depending on how many Markers are present inside a Cluster in a GoogleMaps activity when i tap on one Cluster on the screen, but I get nullPointerException when adding one of this inner ListViews to the main one. The two logs are showing correct data. Here's the code:

java code

```
public class myClusterInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View clusterView;

public myClusterInfoWindow () {
    clusterView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cluster_info_window, null);
}

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.clusterll);

        for (myClusterItem item : clickedCluster.getItems()) {
            View portalView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.portal_info_window, ll, true);
            TextView title = (TextView) portalView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView hacks = (TextView) portalView.findViewById(R.id.hacks);

            title.setText(item.getName());
            hacks.setText(item.getHacks());
            Log.d("CLUSTER", (String) title.getText());
            Log.d("CLUSTER", (String) hacks.getText());
            ll.addView(portalView);     // TODO nullPointerException
        }
        return clusterView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

cluster_info_window.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clusterll">

</LinearLayout>
```

portal_info_window.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_holo_light"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hacks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_holo_light"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot have a `ListView` inside another `ListView`. Or to be more specific: you can, but it will never work right. And having multiple scrollable components inside one another is a general impossibility on Android.

Comment: @XaverKapeller, it looks like they might have confused ListView with LinearLayout, given their code sample.

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about